# How to fit all these flutter widgets in one screen?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]I am building this flutter App. My problem is I canno fit all the widgets in one screen. and all the font sizes and icons seem to be different although they are meant to be the same. In ReusableCard, when the Container height and width properties are set to 200 and 250 respectively, the whole app resizes but they are not uniform as shown in the picture. Does anyone has a suggestion?

```
import 'results_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'icon_content_widget.dart';
import 'reusable_card.dart';
import 'bottom_button.dart';
import 'calculator_brain.dart';

import 'constants.dart';

enum GenderType {
  male,
  female,
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  GenderType selectedGender;
  int height = 180;
  int weight = 60;
  int age = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('CALCULATE BMI'), centerTitle: true),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Container(
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Material(
                  color: Color(0xFF00053C),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: ReusableCard(
                          onPress: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedGender = GenderType.male;
                            });
                          },
                          colour: selectedGender == GenderType.male
                              ? kActiveCardColor
                              : kInactiveCardColor,
                          cardChild:
                              IconContentWidget('MALE', FontAwesomeIcons.mars),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: ReusableCard(
                          onPress: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedGender = GenderType.female;
                            });
                          },
                          colour: selectedGender == GenderType.female
                              ? kActiveCardColor
                              : kInactiveCardColor,
                          cardChild: IconContentWidget(
                              'FEMALE', FontAwesomeIcons.venus),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
            child: Container(
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Material(
                  color: Color(0xFF00053C),
                  child: Row(

                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: ReusableCard(
                          colour: kActiveCardColor,
                          cardChild: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('HEIGHT', style: kLabelTextStyle),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                                textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(height.toString(),
                                      style: kNumberTextStyle),
                                  Text('cm', style: kLabelTextStyle),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SliderTheme(
                                data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                                  activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                                  inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
                                  thumbColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
                                  overlayColor: Color(0x29EB1555),
                                  thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
                                      enabledThumbRadius: 15.0),
                                  overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(
                                      overlayRadius: 30.0),
                                ),
                                child: Slider(
                                  value: height.toDouble(),
                                  min: 120.0,
                                  max: 220.0,
                                  onChanged: (double newValue) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      height = newValue.round();
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Container(
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Material(
                  color: Color(0xFF00053C),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: ReusableCard(
                          colour: kActiveCardColor,
                          cardChild: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'WEIGHT(Kg)',
                                style: kLabelTextStyle,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                weight.toString(),
                                style: kNumberTextStyle,
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  RoundIconButton(
                                    iconName: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        weight--;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  RoundIconButton(
                                    iconName: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        weight++;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: ReusableCard(
                          colour: kActiveCardColor,
                          cardChild: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'AGE',
                                style: kLabelTextStyle,
                              ),
                              Text(age.toString(), style: kNumberTextStyle),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  RoundIconButton(
                                    iconName: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        age--;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  RoundIconButton(
                                    iconName: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        age++;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BottomButton(
            buttonTitle: 'CALCULATE',
            onTap: () {
              CalculatorBrain calc =
                  CalculatorBrain(height: height, weight: weight);
              print(calc);
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return ResultsPage(
                        bmiResult: calc.calculateBMI(),
                        interpretation: calc.getInterpretation(),
                        resultText: calc.getResult());
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onPressed;
  final IconData iconName;

  RoundIconButton({@required this.iconName, this.onPressed});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      fillColor: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 56.0, height: 56.0),
      elevation: 0.0,
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Icon(iconName),
    );
  }
}


class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});
  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap:  onPress,
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 250,
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```